# Is there a way to lower BEP20 smart contract function gas fee costs?

Tags: tokens, gas, fees, bsc

A BEP20 smart contract needs to have a function called periodically (At least once a day) to process some data. The gas fee required to do so is quite high (>0.1 BNB every call). What are some ways to reduce the amount of gas fees required to call this function without changing the smart contract's code or data?

Comment: There could be many ways optimize and cut the costs, but it all depends on the logic. Please walk us thru the logic that the method is executing and provide us with the smart contract code.

Answer (score 1):

I have two suggestions

- You can optimize your code to make it work more efficiently, [here are some tips](https://mudit.blog/solidity-gas-optimization-tips/).
- You can enable the solidity optimizer, see more about it [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/internals/optimizer.html).